# What is the limiting distribution of $$R_n=2(l(\hat{\theta})-l(\tilde{\theta}))$$ under null model $H_0$ for Poisson?

Tags: distributions, self-study, maximum-likelihood

If $X_1,\dots, X_n\sim Poisson (\theta_1)$ and $Y_1,\dots, Y_n\sim Poisson (\theta_2)$, and $X_i$ is independent of $Y_i$, we want to test
$$
H_0: \theta_1=\theta_2, \, H_a: \theta_1\neq \theta_2
$$
What is the limiting distribution of $$R_n=2(l(\hat{\theta})-l(\tilde{\theta}))$$ under null model $H_0$,
where $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE under full model and $\tilde{\theta}$ is MLE under null model.

---

My work:

Under the full model, the MLE is given by
$$
\hat{\theta}_1=\bar{X}\, , \hat{\theta}_2=\bar{Y}
$$
and
under the null model, the MLE is
$$
\tilde{\theta}=\frac{\bar{X}+\bar{Y}}{2}
$$
Then the likelihood ratio test is
$$
R_n=2n\left(\bar{X}\log \frac{2\bar{X}}{\bar{X}+\bar{Y}}-\bar{Y}\log \frac{2\bar{Y}}{\bar{X}+\bar{Y}}\right)
$$
What is this limiting distribution?

We know that from CLE
$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\theta_1)\to^d N(0, \theta_1), \sqrt{n}(\bar{Y}-\theta_2)\to^d N(0, \theta_2)
$$

Comment: Wilk's theorem indicates in general that the asymptotic distribution of $R_n$ is a chi-squared with dregrees of freedom equal to the difference between the number of parameters in your full model and in your null model.  Do you want to derive it by hand in this particular case ?

Comment: @Pohoua Yes, I want to obtain it by hand.